# tried to use thread on my server

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
Source_UDPServer *w = new Source_UDPServer(&tNod);
```

I made it work like this. thanks you all

Answer (score 1):

Arguments for the function to be run by the thread can be provided as additional arguments to the thread object's constructor. Try the following :

```
std::thread first(foo, &udp);
```

See [`std::thread::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) overload #3. Note that all arguments are passed by move or by value. If you need to pass by reference, see [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).